# Floating-point arithmetic in scientific computations rules of thumb

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a nice reference (a review, tutorial, or maybe a book) that has tips and their explanations about general issues of floating-point arithmetic in scientific computations.

Some that I've seen are Numerical Recipes and Goldberg, D. E. (1991). What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic. ACM Computing Surveys, 23(1), 5.

Numerical Recipes is a very large book with specific algorithms. I am looking for general rules of thumb, of general applicability.

The article by Goldberg has a bit too much emphasis on multiple hardware implementations. I really only care about C/C++ programming on modern PCs, which has a pretty standard way of dealing with floats.

Comment: I have always liked the book by Michael Overton called [Numerical Computing with IEEE Floating Point Arithmetic](http://cs.nyu.edu/overton/book/).

Comment: [William Kahan's web site](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/) is a treasure trove of good information.  I also like the relevant chapters from [Nick Higham's Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718027)